# Pycharm type hinting window covers typed code

Tags: pycharm

I have an annoyance with Pycharm. When I start typing anything in the window a little window appears (i'm pretty sure it's a type hinting window) and it covers up what I have typed:

[image]

Under this window I have simply typed `print()`

Anyone know how to move this so it does not block what I've typed? I don't want to get rid of it as it is helpful, just wish to move it below what i've typed.

Env: Win 7 Pro, Pycharm 2017.3 CE.

Kind Regards,
Shawn

Comment: The possible workaround is to close window with `Esc` and reopen it with `Ctrl+P`

Comment: Unable to reproduce - your little window (parameters' hint) is always just about / bellow of the current line, not hiding anything in it.

Comment: @user2235698, that is a great tip!! I have resolved the issue. I just hit enter a few times to bring the first line down a bit and the hint window pops just above the typed line.